# Combinatorial proof of a sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I would like to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k {n \choose k}}=n2^{n-1}$ with a combinatorial proof, once I already know to prove it algebrically. I thought about it in the following way:

Consider a set $S=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ with $n$ elements. How many ways can I choose a subset of S with a leader element?

I) Consider a subset of $S$ with $k+1$ elements. I can start by choosing the $k$ non-leader elements ,${n \choose k}$, and then from the other $n-k$ elements I can choose the leader, ${n-k \choose 1}$. Therefore there exist ${n-k \choose 1}{n \choose k}=(n-k){n \choose k}=(n-k){n \choose n-k}$ ways of choosing a subset of $S$ with $k+1$ elements. Therefore there are $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{(n-k) {n \choose n-k}}$.

II)Every  element can be leader. Therefore for each leader I have to join a subset of $S$ that does not include the leader, $n2^{n-1}$.

Is it a combinatorial proof? I would be very happy if anyone could share a different one.

Comment: It is more clear to me in part I to describe it as ways of choosing a group of k people and then from that group, choose one to be the leader  $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k {n\choose{k}}$.

Comment: I agree with @JohnL. Probably the story should be: "Given $n$ people in how many ways can one choose a (non-empty) group and its leader?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, but what it proves is that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)\binom{n}{n-k}=n2^{n-1}\,;$$

in order to complete the proof, you have to show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)\binom{n}{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}k\,.$$

This isn’t hard:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)\binom{n}{n-k}=\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}k=\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}k\,.$$

But you can avoid this step by using the story suggested in the comments: $k\binom{n}k$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ elements and then choose one of those $k$ to be the leader.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: @Gio: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ be a set with $n$ elements. It is immediate that the set

$$ P_S = \{(A,a) \mid A \subset S \;\land\; a \in A\} $$

contains $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k {n \choose k}}}$ elements.

Consider the set $T = \mathcal{P}(S\setminus\{x_n\}) \times S$ which contains $n \times 2^{n-1}$ elements and the mapping $\beta$ from $T$ to $P_S$ defined by

$\quad \beta(B,x)={\begin{cases}(B,x),&{\text{if }}x\in B\\(B \cup \{x,x_n\},x),&{\text{if }}x \notin B\end{cases}}$

The mapping $\beta$ is readily shown to be both injective and surjective and we conclude that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k {n \choose k}}=n2^{n-1}$$